# why does indexOf doesn't work me in 2 methods

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement, int

I have 2 methods to get protections from `jTextField18.gettext` a string
First method:

```
public boolean isEditValid(String number) {
 for (int i = 0; i <= number.length(); i++)
  if (number.indexOf(i) <= 'a' && number.indexOf(i) >= 'z')
   return true;
 return false;
}
```

Second method:

```
private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 if (jTextField18.getText().isEmpty())
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The text field is emty");
 else if (isEditValid(jTextField18.getText()) == true)
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Edit isnt valid ONLY NUMBERS!");
}
```

When i write on text field a number and a string its says me `Edit isnt valid ONLY NUMBERS` why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate a number, you can use betters ways to do that, for example (using regular expression):

```
public static boolean isEditValid(String number) {
    return number.matches("^[0-9]+$");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as currently written, `isEditValid()` returns `false` if all characters are lower case, and true otherwise.
so i suspect it is not doing what you expect.

i recommend you build a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and test different parameters for `isEditValid()`

also, should it be

```
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
```

instead ? (i have not done any java for a while...)